# Xcode 5.0.1: How to make folders appear on top of files in the Project Navigator

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode5.0.1

I've just started using Xcode and discovered that folders are mixed with files of the same level alphabetically.

Is there a way to have folders displaying on top and then files of the same parent folder? Just like in TextMate's FileBrowser.

**Current displaying is:**

[image]

**I want it to be:**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @Scott pointed out you are using folder references, not groups. If there is no specific reason to use folder references then change to use groups. When dragging in a folder of files there is the option of folder references or groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the MacOS Finder preferences will cause XCode to also display folders before files at the same level.

- Find and check the checkbox under `Finder -> Preferences -> Advanced` labelled `Keep folders on top: In windows when sorting by name`.
- Restart XCode and you will find the new sort order is honored.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just mouse-down on an item and move it. The file or folder level can also be changed this way. You can make folders from the menubar :File:New:Group".

I see that you are using folder references, not groups. If there is no specific reason to use folder references then change to use groups. When dragging in a folder of files there is the option of folder references or groups. Since folder references are a mirror of the directory structure and can not be changed in Xcode. I suspect the OP really wants groups.

When you are at the very bottom you can drag horizontally to select the level to move to. See added image.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your answer, Zaph, unfortunately I'm unable to drag folders up in the Project Navigator within the same parent folder.I have added screenshots hope that helps to understand my problem

Comment: @roody: This might not be possible because you are using folder references, which follow normal OS X ordering (like in Finder). Zaph is using groups, which only exist within the Xcode project. You could change your project so that you have groups instead of folder references, but that may not be feasible if you want to add files from a central location without moving them into your project folder.

Comment: Yes, I failed to notice the folder references. I use only use folder references for things like images and data items. I suspect the OP really wants groups.

Comment: Thanks, Zaph and @Scott, groups can be re-ordered. That's it. Sadly, Xcode doesn't provide a way to display folder references before files.